# I can´t access the information in my session manager after I close my app

Tags: kotlin

I have this session manager. When I log in the first time I get much data like username and userid, but when I close the app and open later, I can't get the information from my session manager.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import com.terracontrol.ui.Activities.InternalActivity
import com.terracontrol.ui.Activities.MainActivity

class SessionManager {

    lateinit var pref: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor
    lateinit var con: Context

    var PRIVATE_MODE = 0

    constructor(con: Context) {
        this.con = con
        pref = con.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
        editor = pref.edit()
        return
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PREF_NAME = "LoginPrefs"
        private const val IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn"
        private const val KEY_USERNAME = "username"
        private const val KEY_USER_ID = "user_id"
    }

    fun createLoginSession(username:String, user_id: Int){
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true)
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username)
        editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID, user_id)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun checkLogin(){
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()){
            var i : Intent = Intent(con, InternalActivity::class.java)
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            con.startActivity(i)
        }
    }

    fun getUserDetails(): HashMap<String, String>{
        var user: Map<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>()
        (user as HashMap).put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null)!!)
        (user as HashMap).put(KEY_USER_ID, pref.getInt(KEY_USER_ID, 0).toString())
        return user
    }


    fun LogoutUser(){
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()
        var i : Intent = Intent(con, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        con.startActivity(i)
    }


    fun isLoggedIn(): Boolean{
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false)
    }
}
```

And this is the way that I call for the information that I need:

```
manager.getUserDetails()["username"]!!
```

I already tried to change the apply to commit.

Comment: Tested no issue with your code. Could you show more of your code using the SessionManager?